# Upgrading Rails, how to autoload constants before config/environment/devlopment.rb runs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

I'm new to Ruby and Rails, so please forgive me if this is a n00b question. I'm trying to upgrade a very old app (using Ruby 2.3.4 and Rails 5.0.6) to the latest versions of Ruby (3.1.3) and Rails (7.0.4).  When config/environment/devlopment.rb executes, I get an uninitialized constant error.  It's trying to access a constant that's defined in a file /lib/settings.rb.  If I try to use this constant in a controller, I have no problems.  However, trying to use this constant in my development.rb causes the error.

I've already added these lines to my application.rb, but it hasn't helped:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

From my research, this seems to be a problem with autoloading, and that the new Rails uses something called Zeitwerk which does loading a bit differently.  However, I'm not sure how to make this work.  Is there a way to get this constant to load before development.rb executes?

Comment: Are you stepping the upgrade the way you need to? You should be upgrading as 5.0 -> 5.1 -> 5.2 -> 6.0 -> 6.1. -> 7.0. See [Upgrading Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) You will need to test and resolve issues, as needed, each step along the way. Jumping straight from 5.0 -> 7.0 is going to be a disastrous mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in `lib` are not supposed to be autoloaded. Please don't add those configuration lines, instead, issue a

```rb
require 'settings'
```

in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Comment: It seems like a lot of the code in this app depends on constants in /lib being autoloaded.  So trying to do 'require' for each one is going to be painful.  Is there some "blanket" way to make sure all the constants in /lib are autoloaded?

Comment: You cannot autoload reloadable constants before the application has booted. That is the only rule. I believed that "I've already added these lines to my application.rb" meant that configuration was not in place before. If the application autoloaded from `lib` you can leave it, but `config/environments/development.rb` needs a `require` for `lib/settings.rb`. That won't conflict, if `Settings` is in memory Zeitwerk will just ignore the file.